# While list length is < 100

Tags: python

I am struggling to get this while loop to work in python.

```
urlList = []
while True: 
    for r in range(1, 5000):
        try:
            response =  urllib.request.urlopen('www.somewebsite.com/v0/info/' + str(r) + '.json')
            html = response.read().decode('utf-8')
            data = json.loads(html)
            if 'url' in data:
                urlList.append(data['url'])
                if len(urlList) == 100: break
        except urllib.error.HTTPError as err:
            print (err)
            continue
print (urlList)
```

I currently have the if statement to break out of the while loop if the list length equals 100. which throws an odd error of urllib.error.URLError:

I also tried While len(urlList) != 100 which makes the process not run.  Also While len(urlList) < 100 just makes it run through the entire range function.

Comment: Sorry I am unclear what you are asking. Is - `'www.somewebsite.com' + str(r) + '.json'` a real url?

Comment: no its an internal URL somewebsite.com is a place holder and stores a bunch of json files which are all 1.json 2.json 3.json etc...

Comment: `www.somewebsite.com' + str(r) + '.json` will give you a malformed URL, you need a `/` between the domain and the file, no?

Comment: What is the exact issue you are facing?

Comment: ok i appended the URL to be more accurate

Comment: the exact issue is I cant get the while loop to function and only run my function until there are 100 items in the list

Comment: if you just print out the current list length, does it increment? as in, swap the if statement with a print?

Comment: what is the problem with `while len(urlList) < 100:` ?

Comment: @owen79 yes it increments when I put print (len(urlList)) after url.List.append

Comment: @AnandSKumar the issue with while len(urlList) < 100 is that it doesnt stop at 100

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your urls are invalid.

```
response =  urllib.request.urlopen('www.somewebsite.com' + str(r) + '.json')
```

This becomes:

```
www.somewebsite.com1.json
www.somewebsite.com2.json
www.somewebsite.com3.json
...
```

These invalid URLs throw an `urllib.error.HTTPError` error.

---

Now that you've corrected the url, the above is invalid. The issue you have is because the `break` is breaking out of your inner loop (the `for`) and dropping you into the `while` loop, which repeats everything again.

Try changing the code to be more like this:

```
urlList = []
for r in range(1, 5000):
     response = ......
     ...
     if 'url' in data:
            urlList.append(data['url'])
            if len(urlList) == 100: break
```

This removes the `while` loop. It keeps the range, which seems to be important to your URLs. When the list reaches a size of 100, it'll break out of this single loop.

Comment: perfect! thanks man I didnt know you can use a break on range...got a 2min timer on marking as answer.....

Answer (score 0):

You have 2 loops but only break once.

You should keep your break as it is to break the for loop, but the while should also have condition as you wrote `while len(urlList)<100`

Both together should exit your loop correctly.

A one more comment, on the response object - call `close()`